# Firing a function that needs to find an element that is loaded into page via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where people can edit items on my site.

When they click on an item the form to edit it is loaded into a div on the page via AJAX with the form fields already filled in depending on which item they chose to edit.

As part of the edit form, I have a 'wysiwyg' editor and I need to enable it with a function but only when the content has loaded in or I get an error that it cannot find the element.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        $("#myDiv").html(this.responseText);
        // myFunction();
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "myPage.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

How can I fire a function once the content has fully loaded in?

Comment: So call the method after you set the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I fire a function once the content has fully loaded in*?

The `.html()` method is synchronous that why it doesn't have a callback, any code
executed after it will definitely occur after the HTML is loaded. But you could use `.promise().done()` to wait.

Since you're using jQuery your code could be simplified to :

```
$.post('myPage.php', function(response){
    $("#myDiv").html(response).promise().done(function(){
        //myFunction();
    });
});
```